# How to access a specific row of a matrix? and how to label axis and turn grid on

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, graph

Given the following matrix:

```
a = [16 456 22 85 93;
     11 78 310 62 36;
      1 66 23 67 405];
```

How do I access its third row? And how to plot that row with grid on, and x-axis labelled as *'sample'* and y-axis labelled as *'value'*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
plot(a(3,:))
grid on
xlabel('sample')
ylabel('value')
```

Note that it is plotting entries in the 3rd row w.r.t to its column number.

Detailed documentation of ***plot*** is available at Mathworks here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?refresh=true

Comment: great Sam! thanks for taking the time to answer this, how would I plot a column instead of a row would this be much change?

Comment: `a(3,:)` means that you're accessing the 3rd row and all the columns of `a`.
Now if you want to access a specific column (say 3rd column) and all the rows of `a`, you can use: `a(:,3)`

Comment: great Sam!! thank you for your help :) is this the same as hold on/hold off?

Comment: @laurajs , If you literally mean it then no. And if you mean something else, I don't get your analogy. Anyway,  `hold on`  holds the current plot and all properties of the axis and you can plot further desired plots in the same figure until you `hold off` which makes it return to the default mode. See documentation here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html